# Android - Function not start

Tags: android

I have this code,

```
String mString = edt_i.getText().toString().substring(0,3);

if (mString == "VIP" || mString == "MEM"){
    checkif();
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Mã "+edt_i.getText().toString()+" không hợp lệ",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

After I get substring "VIP" or "MEM", I compare if it is "VIP" or "MEM", if it true, start `checkif()` method.

Please help me!

Comment: `==` operator compares primitive data values, not objects. Use the `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` method to compare strings instead.

Answer (score 2):

> if (mString == "VIP" || mString == "MEM"){
>                   checkif();
>               }

replace this with

```
if (mString.equals("VIP" )|| mString.equals"MEM"){
                checkif();
            }
```

For comparing strings use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` method not **==**.